# is there a way to delay an if statement/method in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have a problem with delaying a method from happening in a if statement, this if statement is in another method called OnCollisionExit(). The purpose of this mess is to try to prolong another method in another if statement in another method called OnCollisionStay().

I've made a timer, which actually works. The problem (I think) is that OnCollisionExit() runs through its code only one time... therefore the timer doesn't work (it doesn't reach zero). If you don't undrestand you will do when you read the code

timer method (it is run in the Update() method)

```
private void Counter()
    {
        if (counterEnabled)
        {
            remainingTime = remainingTime - 1 * Time.deltaTime;
        }
        if (remainingTime <= 0)
        {
            remainingTime = defaultTime;
            counterEnabled = false;
        }

    }
```

this is the OnCollisionExit() method

```
void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        counterEnabled = true;
        if (collision.gameObject == thing && counterEnabled == false)
        {
            //this is what am trying to delay
            DontDoSomething();
        }

    }
```

this is the OnCollisionStay() method

```
void OnCollisionStay(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject == thing)
        {
            //this is what Iam trying to prolong
            DoSomething();
        }
     }
```

if you don't know how the timer works... it works like this:

- when OnCollisionExit() runs, it will make a bool (counterEnabled) true
- when this happens, a variable(remainingTime) of value 2f will get subtracted by 1 every second
- when remainingTime reaches zero or anything less, remainingTime will be equal to defaultTime which is simply a variable holding remainingTime original value (2f), and will turn counterEnabled false.
- when counterEnabled turns false, it will allow the if statement in OnCollisionExit() to be true

Comment: Your final solution is going to depend on what you're actually trying to achieve, but a lock or similar first-class concurrency structure could help here.   See http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a coroutine instead :

```
void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
{
        StartCoroutine (Countdown());
}

IEnumerator Countdown() 
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (2f);
    DontDoSomething ();
}
```